# Autolayout in UIScrollView dynamic content with UIButton at bottom

Tags: ios, button, dynamic, autolayout, scrollview

I have to do a form in my application with dynamic content (it comes for a web service). So, I need a scroll for the case there are many textfields and there not fit in the screen. And under of all the textfields I need a button to save the info. My problem is that if there are few textfields (that fit in the screen) the button have to appear at bottom of the screen, and not under the last textfield.
I'm using autolayout programmaticaly to add the constraints of the textfields and add them in the view one under the previous one, but I don't know what constraints I have to set to the save button.

I have uploaded two images to explain that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaPp0.png

In the first image I have only two textfields, that fit in the screen, so the screen not scroll and the save button appear at the bottom of the screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqVve.png

In this second image, there are many textfields, so the screen need to scroll and the save button will be under the textfields (at 20 pixels or something like that), and not at bottom at screen.

Do you can help me? Thanks for all.

Comment: are you adding textfields dynamically?

Comment: Yes. I don't know how many textfields I will have in the layout, because it come in a web service. I need so the do it dynamically.

Comment: are your textfields are getting added properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below constraint to your save button -

1) Vertical space constraint to your last added UITextfield
2) Center horizontal constraint to your content view
3) Height and width constraint

Or

1) Bottom constraint to your content view
2) Center horizontal constraint to your content view
3) Height and width constraint
4) your last added textfield bottom constraint to Save button